# datediff comparison with todays date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to do a datediff with today and a date that was entered in the past

I tried the below but my results are unexpected

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);

$expires2 = $SQL->query("SELECT DATEDIFF(datez, $today) AS SUBVAL FROM row WHERE id='$id' AND DATEDIFF(datez, $today) > -1");
$expiredval = $SQL->fetch_array($expires2);
```

and this gives a blank result

The below works but I would like to do this in php

```
$expires2 = $SQL->query("SELECT DATEDIFF(datez, $today) AS SUBVAL FROM row WHERE id='$id' AND DATEDIFF(datez, $today) > -1");
```

I am not sure how to create a new column in mysql that is just today  (it wasn't working when I tried)

Comment: I cant see a difference between first query and second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL function `CURDATE()` the get the system current date instead of injecting a PHP variable, like `DATEDIFF(datez, CURDATE())`.